# Crear carpeta en PHP

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando un proyecto en el cual tengo que crear una carpeta por usuario

```
$carpeta = '/ruta/a/mi/carpeta';
if (!file_exists($carpeta)) {
    mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true);
}
```

estoy utilizando esta forma de hacerlo pero no me genera la carpeta hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo o estoy agregando algo mal

Comment: php tiene permisos para crearla?? puedes validar haciendo un `mkdir($carpeta, 0777, true)? echo "creada" : "surgio un error!";`

Comment: Desconozco lo intentare y en seguida te comento

Comment: no tiene permisos como se los puedo dar ?

Comment: debes darle permisoss a las carpetas si es `windows` con click derecho en propiedad si es `linux` con chmod -R 770 /carpeta/

Comment: @RamiroRM que sistema operativo usas?

Comment: Utilizo windows 10